# How to make a rectangle of characters?

Tags: java

How to make a rectangle of characters? 
I need to make such a picture appear in the console

```
 **********
*          *
*          *
*          *
 **********
```

But I get this:

```
********* 
********* 
********* 
********* 
*********
```

Sides a and b are entered from the console.

```
    int a = requestNumber();
    int b = requestNumber();
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            if (j == 0 || j < (b - 1))
            System.out.print("*");
            else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (j == 0 || j < (b - 1))` should be `if (j == 0 || j == (b - 1))`

Comment: Then you need a row of `*` at the start and the end. Should be very easy to include this.

Comment: You need to be testing `i` to determine whether you're on the top margin, or on the bottom margin, or somewhere in between.

Comment: @akuzminykh thanks, but I don’t understand how to add the top and bottom line, since there is always a line break character

Comment: What are the values for `a` and `b` supposed to be for the given expected picture?

Comment: @akuzminykh values ​​are set from the console (Scanner)

Comment: You showed us a rectangle at the top of the question. What values would have to be entered in the console for that rectangle to be printed?

Comment: You need to enter the width (int a) and height (int b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty concise way to do it just a few lines:

```
int a = requestNumber();
int b = requestNumber();

System.out.println(" " + new String(new char[a]).replace("\0", "*"));
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {           
    System.out.println("*" + new String(new char[a]).replace("\0", " ") + "*");
}
System.out.println(" " + new String(new char[a]).replace("\0", "*"));
```

EDIT: Fixed typo, works now!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Rectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.printRectangle(7,9);
    }

    private void printRectangle(int row, int col) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if ((isFirstOrLastRow(i, row) && isFirstOrLastCol(j, col))
                        || !(isFirstOrLastRow(i, row) || isFirstOrLastCol(j, col))) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private boolean isFirstOrLastRow(int currentRow, int row) {
        return currentRow == 0 || currentRow == row - 1;
    }

    private boolean isFirstOrLastCol(int currentCol, int col) {
        return currentCol == 0 || currentCol == col - 1;
    }
}
```

The four corners and the middle position should output spaces, so we should judge whether it is the four corners or the middle position，I use isFirstOrLastRow and isFirstOrLastCol to help judge.

here is the result for input 7,9

```
 ******* 
*       *
*       *
*       *
*       *
*       *
 *******
```